# BASE DE DATOS Inner Join?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web

Me explico. Tengo 2 tablas una que se llama Asociado y otra que se llama Haber. En la tabla Asociado tengo una columna que se llama cedula el cual es mi primary key y otros datos relacionados a ese usuario. La tabla Haber tiene su columna id, una columna que se llama CedulaAsociado y esta está relacionada a la columna cedula de asociado y otros datos mas a llenar. Quiero que el administrador después de registrar todos los asociados ella vaya a la parte de Haberes y tenga una lista con todas las cedulas registradas y al lado los campos de haberes a llenar. Cómo haría? tendría que usar un inner join? y de ser así, cómo lo haría?

intenteté esto  `$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO  haber (cedulaAsociado) SELECT cedula FROM asociado where tipoUsuario = 2");` pero nada. entonces no sé si necesite un inner Join. Mas adelante necesitaré ver detalles de algún asociado en específico donde se mostrarán los datos de ambas tablas y no sé si funcione. 
acá una parte de la normalización de la tabla

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLaSJ.png]

Comment: Listo, lo edité. Espero así pueda aclarar mi duda

Comment: ¿Para qué usas `INSERT`? ¿Quieres visualizar o insertar datos?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres sacar los datos de una tabla relacionados con otra tabla tienes que hacer un inner join si o si. Lo que estas haciendo con el insert es insertar datos.

Para realizar un inner join es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT asociado.*, haber.* FROM asociado
INNER JOIN haber ON asociado.cedula = haber.cedulaAsociado;
```

Puedes realizar tantos inner joins como quieras si despues lo tienes que hacer con la otra tabla.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ASOC.PRIMER_NOMBRE,ASOC.PRIMER_APELLIDO, ASOC.CORREO

Seleccionas los datos que tienes en la tabla de "asociado" y así puedes realizar los inner join para que puedas sacar datos de otra tabla.

FROM ASOCIADO ASOC INNER JOIN HABER HA
ON ASOC.IDHABER_ASOCIADO= HA.IDHABER.

Con este inner puedes hacer con la otra tabla.
```